# Open_GL Camera somehow not centered

Tags: opengl

I setup my OpenGL viewport via

```
    ViewPort( 0,0,WindowW, WindowH )
    MatrixMode( Projection )
    LoadIdentity()
    MaxY = ClipNear * Tan(FieldOfView * 0.00872664626)
    MaxX = MaxY * Ratio
    Frustrum(-MaxX ,MaxX ,-MaxY ,MaxY ,ClipNear ,ClipFar)
    MatrixMode(ModelView)
```

Then I add rotation and move the Camera accordingly

```
    LoadIdentity()
    Rotated(ry,1,0,0)
    Rotated(rx,0,1,0)
    Translated(z,y,x)
```

However the center of the frustrum is not the middle of the Window.
It is slightly right and up in the window.

I'm sure there is a bug in my code but I can't seem to find it.
I have checked every place I could think of.

The bug could be caused by setting a wrong viewport however that doesn't seem to be the case as a similar Project (however not using modular code) works fine with the same viewport settings.

The bug could also be caused by setting a wrong Frustrum. However that also works in the other project.

Aside from that I do not know of anything that could cause this.

As my Code is written in a rather weird language posting it here wouldn't do any good.

So my question is what kind of mistake/bug can cause a behaviour like that.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that my Window had the wrong size.
Background:
I use a full screen Window that simply has no border. I set the size of that Window to the Screen Resolution. Now the problematic part:
While the size of the Window is respecting DPI the resolution returned doesn't which lead to a window thats too large.